# How can I open a C++ or Java project S60 5th Edition SDK 1.0 with Netbeans

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, symbian, s60

I installed S60 5th Edition SDK 1.0 but I can't open project on netbeans? How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a java project, you need to install the Mobility plugin. go to the `Tools/Plugins` menu, and select `Mobility` in the `Available plugins` tab.

once you installed the plugin, you need to add the S60 SDK as a platform: go to the `Tools/Java Platform` menu and click on the `Add platform` button. In the dialog window which opens, select `Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator` and click `Next`. NetBeans will then search your system for an available platform. if the SDK has been properly installed, it will promptly be listed as an available platform to be added to NetBeans.

remember that the Nokia SDK have to be installed in a directory which name does not contain a space.